# Why can I use constants as statements in C?

Tags: c

Why does this program below not show any error ?

```
int main (void) {
    "ANGUS";
    1;
    3.14;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are just statements without effect and have not broken any rules.

Comment: +1 for a well posed question though.

Comment: Side question: is memory allocated for the string `"Harsha"`?

Comment: I've wondered the same myself.  Since it does nothing, it is almost certainly a typo in the code, so why doesn't the compiler complain.  One I've seen before was of the form a;b++; where the middle semicolon was meant to be a dot.  It happened that the b variable existed independantly, as well as a member of the structure.  No error but the program didn't behave as expected!

Comment: @Chris: even with the most basic optimization options, the result of compiling a source file with or without the `"Harsha";` line is exactly the same. With no optimization whatsoever, the construct follows the rules for `string literals`: "6.4.5/5 ... array of static storage duration" and there will be 7 bytes allocated for it.

Comment: @asc99c: **OUCH!** That's a tough one. `gcc` complains if you ask it nicely: `gcc -Wunused-value ...` or `gcc -Wall ...`

Comment: @pmg the problem was on AIX, and I've never found any XLC warning options I can enable that don't throw out tons of spurious rubbish :)  The number of potential issues we found when the codebase was first moved cross-platform, and we could use the more sensible gcc warnings, was stunning!  gcc's tracking of printf arguments, and warning about errors, is a wonderful feature.

Comment: @asc99c: I suspect you've simplified the names in question to `a` and `b` in this case, but if that's what they actually were, this sounds like another good reason to use more descriptive variable names, though I suppose you could run into the same issue with somewhat-descriptive things like `myStruct.name` and `name`...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Each of those statements are expressions that evaluate to a value, which is then discarded.
Compare it to if you called a function that returned an int, a char or a float, without using the return value. That's also an expression that evaluates to a value.

It is not uncommon to have functions that return values that the caller may or may not be interested in, like for example where `printf("%d", 9001)` returns the number of characters printed. A caller can use the number returned, or they can just ignore it.

If the compiler complained whenever you ignored a return value, you'd have a very noisy build log. Some compilers however diagnose (if sufficient warning flags are enabled) such pointless side-effect-less uses of literals and variables.

Comment: Add an example and get a +1 from me ... oh, never mind: +1 anyway ... but add the example :)

Comment: `printf("Hello, world!\n");` returns the value 14

Comment: @pmg, I like how you added your own example two minutes later... :p

Answer (score 16):

It's perfectly valid for a statement in C to be just a value that gets discarded. Most people don't realise that this is exactly what happens when they code up things like:

```
x++;
printf ("Hello, world\n");
```

The former is actually an expression which just happens to have the side effect of incrementing the variable after "returning" it.

The latter function call actually returns a value (the number of characters printed) which is also discarded.

From a certain viewpoint, that is no different from the statements:

```
42;
3 * 12;
```

other than the fact that they have no side effects which make them useful.

In fact, even `x = 1` is an expression where the result is discarded. It is this that makes `x = y = z = 0` possible since this is effectively:

```
(x = (y = (z = 1)));
```

All of this is detailed in C99, section `6.8.3 Expression and null statements` which says, in part:

> The expression in an expression statement is evaluated as a void expression for its side
>   effects, such as assignments, and function calls which have side effects.

Answer (score 9):

It is perfectly valid for a statement to consist of just an expression. Nothing is achieved by doing so in your examples, but it's perfectly valid all the same.

Answer (score 5):

Since in c it's a valid statement but when you use java it will give you compile time error.

Comment: In English, u is spelled you

Comment: thanks for the edit... i will keep this in mind no shortcuts specially for "you" next time...

Comment: +1, because it bears mentioning that while this **is** valid C syntax (as everyone here is asserting ad nauseum), it is *not* valid syntax in many other languages (i.e. Java & C#).

Answer (score 4):

Why should it? The first three lines in you main don't do anything and return 0; is a valid expression.

If you use gcc to compile the program try to enable all warnings (with -Wall parameter). This would print `warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: In gcc, `-Wall` does not enable **all** warnings: it enables "warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable" (from [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html))

Comment: @Mr.32 pmg is right, `-Wall` does not enable all warnings but only "warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable"

Comment: `return 0;` is a statemwnt, not an ezpression.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is valid. A string or a number is a valid expression and an expression followed by semi-colon is a statement (also informally known as instruction).

Comment: by comma? is the ";" symbol named comma?

Comment: and not an instruction but "statement" (according to ISO standard )

Comment: It's called a "statement expression".

Answer (score 0):

It is also valid in C++ and it does have a hackish use in Visual Studio where you wish to "Find All References" for an enum, you can type the enum on a line by itself terminated with a semicolon and you can use the context menu to find the references.